# Add year to column before compare in SQL query

Tags: sql, mysql

I am querying a MySQL database and I need to add a year to a column (of type date) before the compare operation.

I would expect is to look something like this:

```
SELECT count(*) AS count 
  FROM users 
 WHERE renewed + 1 year < '2009-12-12'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count 
  FROM USERS u 
 WHERE DATE_ADD(u.renewed, INTERVAL 1 YEAR) < '2009-12-12'
```

Reference:

- [DATE_ADD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

Comment: +1. But just ` WHERE u.renewed + INTERVAL 1 YEAR < '2009-12-12'` should also work

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [mysql DATE_ADD function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add):

```
DATE_ADD(renewed, INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
```